# Access into insert Error: Entering number into Access number field

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I wrote a java program using Access database I can record String values but the query I write for number Values using a number field column generates a INSERT INTO error. Below is the query and error.

```
Level - Col in table with number field

Access Insert Statement:
INSERT INTO SystemEquipment(Level) Values (12);

Error:
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

**Tried to run the query with and without single quotes and semicolons
```

Answer (score 4):

because `LEVEL` is a reserved keyword. You must escape it using `[]`

```
INSERT INTO SystemEquipment([Level]) Values (12);
```

- [MS Access Reserved Keywords](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

From MS Access Docs,

> If a reserved word is already in use, **you can avoid error messages by
>   surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets ([])** . However,
>   the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.